# Browser automation: Data sets from Excel Vba into Firefox

Tags: excel, browser-automation, vba

actually I am using imacros for firefox to automate some things and it works for me.

But when it comes to filling out some data sets from an excel sheet to browser for example. Imacros for firefox does not reach. I was reading about selenium, chromium etc. But I dont know whats the right tool.

So I am asking u exactly. Imagine an excel sheet with a data set of hundreds addresses like A2 = Name B2 = Street and C2 = Zip Code etc. Every data set has to be copied to the browser.

But I really dont know how to do it.

Has someone a solution?

Thanks for ur help

Comment: Why firefox and not IE? (Just curious)

Comment: Use selenium basic and use sendkeys to populate values. An URL would have helped make this an [MCVE] and/or sufficient HTML.

Answer (score 0):

if u have a solution in IE. It is ok as well. But I am prefering Firefox and Chrome. So it would be interesting to know how to solve the problem using Excel VBA and Firefox.

I dont know if it is the right way, but could it work using Excel vba and selenium web driver?